# Shuffle single column in pandas by a fixed percentage

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, shuffle

I am trying to shuffle single column in pandas by a fixed percentage (2% of rows in each iteration. Total iterations = 30) in each iteration using Sklearn utils shuffle function. But it doesn't change the original dataframe. Is there any way I can apply this operation on the original dataframe? Or is there any alternative approach? Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

for i in range(0, 30, 2):
    percent = (i/100) * len(df_task2_train)
    shuffle(df_task2_train['class'], n_samples=int(percent))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning the result and sklearn outputs numpy arrays: try something like

```
shuffled_dfs = [None] * len(range(0, 30, 2))
for i in range(0, 30, 2):
    percent = (i/100) * len(df_task2_train)
    shuffled_dfs[i] = pd.DataFrame(shuffle(df_task2_train['class'], n_samples=int(percent)))
```

if you want to concat all resulting df you can with

`shuffled_df = pd.concat(shuffled_dfs)`

Frankly I would not have used sklearn but [pandas.DataFrame.sample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) so that you don't have to switch between numpy arrays and pandas dataframes